Solving the expression of tortoise coordinate differential equation in Mathematica
I want to solve the differential equation of the form
$\dfrac{dr_*}{dr} = \dfrac{1}{\left(1-\dfrac{2M}{r}\right)}$
under the boundary conditions $\lim_{r \rightarrow 2M}r_*(r) \rightarrow - \infty$ and $\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty}r_*(r) \rightarrow \infty$
The solution of the above differential equation is
$r_*(r) = r + 2M\ln\left(\dfrac{r-2M}{2M}\right)$.
I have written a code for doing the same. But the code is not working.
$Assumptions = M >= 0 && r >= 0;
DSolve[{rstar'[r] == (1/(1 - 2 M/r)), rstar[2 M] == -Infinity, rstar[Infinity] == Infinity}, rstar[r], r]


I will be glad if someone can help me with the code.

Please add the Mathematica code instead of a image. Code can be copied and run; an image cannot.

Doesn't Integrate[1/(1 - 2 M/r), r] give you what you want?

DSolve works without your boundary conditions specified and it looks like they are met anyway.  A first order equation takes only one bc.

@creidhne I have added the code.

@JimB No. It is not returning the expected.

@BillWatts. You are right. Just first boundary condition is sufficient.
